# Data not entering into wampserver sql database using php functions

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, wampserver

Here is the php code. I am also new to php and queries, is my query wrong because or any logical mistake because the data is not reflecting in the table named as user. registration.php is also include. Beginner in php hard to understand can u pinpoint the mistake.

```
<?php
//connect to the database 
$db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','register') or die("not connected");
if($db){
    echo "connection s";
}
global $errors;
global $sql;
//if next bustton is clicked
    if(isset($_POST['Next'])){
        $first =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first name']);
        $last =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last name']);
        $regno =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['reg no']);
        //all fields filled
        if(empty($first)){
            array_push($errors,"First name is required");
        }
        if(empty($last)){
            array_push($errors,"Last name is required");
        }
        if(empty($regno)){
            array_push($errors,"Registration number is required");
        }

        //error free then there are no errors,save it in database
        if(count($errors)==0){

            $sql="insert into users (first name, last name, regno) values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')";
            $query=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            if($query){
                echo "query inserted";
            }

        }
    }
```

?>
  here main registration.php start

```
<?php include('server.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">          
        <h2>Book Bank Registration</h2>
            <form action="registration.php" method="POST">
                <?php include('errors.php'); ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>First Name</label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Registration No</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="regno">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--label for="next">Next</label-->
        <input type="submit" value="Next" class="form-control" name="next">
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

here the method is POST

Comment: You have many issues, but you need to enclose column names that have a space `\`first name\``

Comment: yeah did that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try edit code:

```
$_POST['first name'] => $_POST['first_name']
$_POST['last name'] => $_POST['last_name']
$_POST['reg no'] => $_POST['reg_no']

$sql="insert into users (first name, last name, regno) values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')";
```

to

```
$sql="insert into users (first_name, last_name, regno) 
        values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')";
```

`first name` is not a field in the users table in MySQL, it should be `first_name` or `firstname`, the same for `last name` and `reg no`

Comment: changed that too firstname and for all the variables and name

Comment: there was a problem with myaqli_real_escaoe_string() removed it .It works fine now but ther is warning showing as " count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable "

Comment: Very happy with that @john

Answer (score 0):

Use of mysql_real_escape_string can cause an error in a mysqli_connect database...
Instead use mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$field);

For now try  `mysqli_query($db,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($db)).`

```
<?php
    //connect to the database 
    $db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','register') or die("not connected");
    if($db){
        echo "connection s";
    }
    global $errors;
    global $sql;
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //if next bustton is clicked
        if(isset($_POST['next'])){
            $first =mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['firstname']);
            $last =mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['lastname']);
            $regno =mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['regno']);
            //all fields filled
            if(empty($first)){
                array_push($errors,"First name is required");
            }
            if(empty($last)){
                array_push($errors,"Last name is required");
            }
            if(empty($regno)){
                array_push($errors,"Registration number is required");
            }
            var_dump($errors);
            echo "<br/>Count of errors ".count($errors);
    //error free then there are no errors,save it in database
            if(count($errors)==0){
                $sql="insert into users (firstname, lastname, regno) values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')";
                $query=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
                if($query){
                    echo "query inserted";
                }
                else{
                    echo mysqli_error($db);
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Errors Variable.";
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "No Post Done";
        }
}
```

Comment: Do a var_dump of error before if block check if it is empty or not.

Comment: no error is showing when i put variable like var_dump($first);

Comment: :( no it is also not working can u check my sql query of 'insert into' is it  correct ?

Comment: Seems like you have a space in between your field name I.e. first name? In that case you have to use `first name` in your query

Comment: yeah the the field name first name has also space in database (does it conflict?)

Comment: In that case you have to use <pre>`first name`</pre>. Use quote which is above tab key in keyboard. I am unable to write that quote symbol here

Comment: after editing with if(count($errors)==0){ Echo "Inside if block"; no there was no message displayed after entering data in the form

Comment: Write an else to your if... If no message is displayed than it means it is not entering your  if block. Try to do a var_dump($errors); before if block.

Comment: I now removed all the spaces in the field name of database and also edited the code but still not working

Comment: C:\wamp64\www\library\server.php:9:null
it is shwoing me this message for var_dump($errors)

Comment: there may be an error of form submission. The button or input type by which submit of form has been done should have name='Next' and action of the form should be post.

Comment: i will include the main registration.php in above can you please check

Comment: sure. Seems like you are new to PHP development. you can clarify your concepts of form handling in PHP using: [link]https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Thanks brother for your help just removed the mysqli_escape_string() function it works but there is a warning  as "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable"

Answer (score 0):

Try to output your error message with [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php):

```
<?php

//...

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if (!$query) {
  echo mysqli_error($db);
}

//...
```

Comment: no there is no error showing even after replacing it with your edited code :(

Comment: Are your table name and its field names correct? try these:
``"insert into `users` (`first name`, `last name`, `regno`) values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')"`` or ``"insert into `users` (`first_name', 'last_name', 'regno') values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')"`` or ``"insert into `user` (`first_name', 'last_name', 'regno') values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')"``

Comment: using this query "insert into `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `regno`) values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')"   all the fields here are in the database with correct name still not working

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$db->real_escape_string
```

insead of

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first name']);


    <?php
//connect to the database 
$db=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '','register') or die("not connected");
if($db){
    echo "connection s";
}
global $errors;
global $sql;
//if next bustton is clicked
    if(isset($_POST['Next'])){
        $first =$db->real_escape_string($_POST['first name']);
        $last =$db->real_escape_string($_POST['last name']);
        $regno =$db->real_escape_string($_POST['reg no']);
        //all fields filled
        if(empty($first)){
            array_push($errors,"First name is required");
        }
        if(empty($last)){
            array_push($errors,"Last name is required");
        }
        if(empty($regno)){
            array_push($errors,"Registration number is required");
        }

        //error free then there are no errors,save it in database
        if(count($errors)==0){

            $sql="insert into users (first name, last name, regno) values ('$first', '$last', '$regno')";
            $query=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
            if($query){
                echo "query inserted";
            }

        }
    }
```